# Left join expression and amount of rows returned by Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, relational-database, left-join

A query with left join is not returning records, although the where clause from the left table should find a single record. In this case, it should return a record with the fields from the left table containing values and from the right table null, since there is no match between them.

Apparently there is a problem with the use of case that references the right table on the join expression.

In SQL Server the same query worked as expected.

```
select 
  t1.Description, t2.Description
from 
  A t1 
left join 
  B t2 
on
  t1.Id = t2.Id and
  1 = case when (
    t2.Id = t2.Id and 
    (select t3.Flag from C t3 where t3.ID_B = t2.Id) = 'S'
  ) then 1 else 0 
  end
where t1.Id = 1
```

Result: no rows returned.

Then I moved the expression `t2.Id = t2.Id` (that is here only to demonstrate the problem and should always return true, apparently) out of the case expression.

```
select 
  t1.Description, t2.Description
from 
  A t1 
left join 
  B t2 
on
  t1.Id = t2.Id and
  t2.Id = t2.Id and 
  1 = case when ( 
    (select t3.Flag from C t3 where t3.ID_B = t2.Id) = 'S') then 1 else 0 
  end
where t1.Id = 1
```

Result: one row returned.

The queries above only serve to demonstrate the problem, are not useful in a real situation and not optimized.

I want to know if anyone knows any limitation of Oracle related to this case. So far we believe it is a bug.

Data used:

- A: Id=1, Description=Item A1;
- B: Id=1, Description=Item B1;
- C: Id=1, Id_B=2, Flag=S.

Comment: I would not call it a bug, I woudl call it a differnt implementation. SQL Server and ORacle are not clones. And frankly I personally would worry more about my own database design if you feel the need to put a case statement of any kind in a join.

Comment: To double check my understanding of the problem, you expected that the first query would return one row?

Comment: Here are test table and the problem query for anyone looking at this. Run the query then view the execution plan. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/449ba/4

Comment: This is strange: "the where clause from the left table should find a single record". A WHERE clause is applied to the result of all the JOINs in a FROM clause. It isn't "from the left table". Here it is applied to (the result of) the left join. Maybe that's what you meant to say?

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: I've tested in Oracle 10 and 11. I meant that one row should be returned because where clause `t1.Id = 1` match one record from table A. Since left join expression doesn't match a record from table B, `t2.Description` should be printed null.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `t2.id = t2.id` is always true is wrong.  If the value were `NULL` that would be treated as false.  I don't believe that is relevant for this particular example, but just to clarify.

The question is how is a `left join` processed.  The idea is simple.  The `on` clause is processed.  If there are no matches, then the row from the first table is kept.  This is regardless of what is in the `on` clause.  (This is a functional description; there are many possible implementations.)

Based on your sample data, Oracle is incorrect.  One row should be returned.  The SQL Server example should also return one row.  I suspect that the data might be subtly different; I personally have never had issues with `left join`s in SQL Server (or Oracle).

Comment: @philipxy . . . You are correct (;).  That seemed to be a typo/misspelling, but it totally changed the meaning.

Comment: @philipxy . . . For a `left join`, the `on` clause is calculated as a whole.  Either there is a match or there is not match.  When there is no match, an inner join produces no output.  A `left join` produces the row from the first table with `NULL` values for the columns in the second.  What happens with in the `on` clause is immaterial to this behavior.  If you want to have fun with `left join`, but a filter condition in the *first* table, and ponder why it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just mean that your word choice in your answer's first paragraph is unclear re where in the expression & conceptual processing what things can have what values for what input. Similarly "What happens with in the on clause is immaterial to this behaviour" seems strange since the on clause is what determined the matches.

Comment: @philipxy . . . I see.  Totally good point.  I was responding to a statement in the text and not thinking clearly enough about the context of the query it was coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual);
CREATE TABLE t2 AS (SELECT 2 ID FROM dual);
CREATE TABLE t3 AS (SELECT 2 id_b, 's' flag FROM dual);

SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
      ON t1.ID = t2.ID
         AND 1 = CASE WHEN t2.id = t2.id and (SELECT flag FROM t3 WHERE t3.id_b = t2.ID) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
where t1.id = 1;
```

The output: `no rows selected`

The result looks strange, I suppose it can be a bug.

Oracle documentation only states
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52337

> You cannot compare a column with a subquery in the WHERE clause of any
>   outer join, regardless which form you specify.

By looking on the plan of the above query I can see that this condition:

```
 AND 1 = CASE WHEN t2.id = t2.id and (SELECT flag FROM t3 WHERE t3.id_b = t2.ID) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Is interpreted as:

```
 CASE WHEN (T2.ID(+)=T2.ID(+) AND (SELECT FLAG FROM T3 T3 WHERE T3.ID_B=:B1)='s') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1
```

and is **calculated after the join**.

I suppose that Oracle cannot calcuate the CASE until the join is performed (because of `T2.ID(+)=T2.ID(+)`)

Comment: I guess there's a sense in which *given* that it's using the post-left-join value of t2.id in the case it "cannot" do so in the ON; but it *shouldn't* use that value in the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLFiddle Oracle 11g R2 (thanks to Shannon Severance) your first query gives Record Count: 0 but by simply removing the CASE we get Record Count: 1. (Note the renaming of t2Description.)

```
create table A (ID number(38), Description varchar(10));
create table B (ID number(38), Description varchar(10));
create table C (ID number(38), ID_B number(38), Flag varchar(10));

insert into A values(1, 'Item A1');
insert into B values(2, 'Item B1');
insert into C values(1, 2, 'S');

select 
  t1.Description, t2.Description as t2d
from 
  A t1 
left join 
  B t2 
on
  t1.Id = t2.Id and
    t2.Id = t2.Id and 
    (select t3.Flag from C t3 where t3.ID_B = t2.Id) = 'S'
where t1.Id = 1
```

This suggests that it has something to do with CASE being miscalculated.

Note that in the ON t2.Id is at least sometimes (correctly) taken to be the value from the FROM cross product, not NULL which it is after the ON:

```
select 
  t1.Description, t2.Description as t2d
from 
  A t1 
left join 
  B t2 
on
    -- for above data t2.id should be 1 here
    t2.id is null
where t1.Id = 1
-- for above data t2.id should be null here

DESCRIPTION     T2D
Item A1     (null)
```

I found this link: [Outer Join Bug in Oracle 12c?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3548388)